# Chrome not responding to css animation/transform, but Firefox works fine

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I'm trying to spin an svg element. It works fine in Firefox 25, but not in Chrome 31 (both the current, latest, release versions). Here is the code http://codepen.io/zshift/pen/Fvibj, but shown below for easy reading:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        @-webkit-keyframes spinners {
          from {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
          }
          to {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
          }
        }

        @keyframes spinners {
          from {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
          }
          to {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
          }
        }

        .spinner {
           -webkit-animation: spinners 1s infinite linear;
           -moz-animation: spinners 0.75s infinite linear;
           -o-animation: spinners 1s infinite linear;
        /*   animation: spinners 1s infinite;*/
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <svg class="spinner" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
          <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
```

I don't see any errors or warnings in Chrome, and I'm following the guides I've read on http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp, but no luck. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the prefix for `transform`

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);

@-webkit-keyframes spinners {
 from {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 to {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
```

The demo **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fJCki**